# contact form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

http://localhost/ahalia/contact-us/#wpcf7-f606-o1

I am using a contact form 7 plugin. when I am clicking the submit button, the url goes like given above. what is this `#wpcf7-f606-o1`? Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Please share a live link. Your localhost link will not help us in helping you

Comment: can you show us how the form in the admin page looks like? did you change anything on the submit tag ?

Answer (score 2):

It's an [anchor](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.3). It makes the browser jump directly to the contact form after the page is loaded. This is useful when you have the form below a long page, so the user doesn't have to scroll down to see potential error messages regarding the form.

Answer (score 1):

Your submit button might be an anchor tag with href="#wpcf7-f606-o1", that is why your url goes like given above.

**EDIT**

If your form looks like

```
<form action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f606-o1" method="get" class="wpcf7-form" >
```

Then **wpcf7-f606-o1** is your form's reference id.

If you don't want this in your url then change the **method** from **get** to **post** .

Comment: no...actually I am using the submit button in contact form 7....

Comment: Changing the method will not make any difference.

Comment: <form action="/contact-us/#wpcf7-f606-o1" method="get" class="wpcf7-form" > cannot find this code in the plugin

Comment: I wanted to know if contact form 7 plugin can be used in a popup window ?

Comment: @anumol you can use it on modal.

Comment: modal meaning ? Actualy i am using a contact form 7 in a popup window. On clicking the submit button, the popup window closes and the message "Your message has been successfully send" is visible only when we click the popup tab again. I dont know how to solv this problem

Comment: @anumol , I think due to some reason you are not sharing your code or live link here, You can contact me personally where I can help you more. my mail id - swarnendu.prof@gmail.com

Comment: ok..i will contact you.I have tried many alternatives which everyone told here but its still not working..

Answer (score 1):

It's a unit-tag of the form. Actually, from the contact-form.php of the plugin, you may find the get_unit_tag function that generate the tag.
You may get rid of the tag in the url by customize the plugin, but if you are not familiar with PHP or not aware of what you are doing, I suggest you not do that.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a configuration issue. Please check whether you have called `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` in `header.php` and `footer.php` respectively.